# How to parse user who clicked a button

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When a user registers, they are redirected to /proto (which shows a list of animals available for adoption). Here's the problem, how do i get the exact user who clicked the button (cause this needs to be parsed alongside the exact pet selected) to the /adminPage.
Below is my code app.js

```
//jshint esversion:6
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var multer = require('multer');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var imgModel = require('./model');

const app = express();


var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');



app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json())

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/sanctDB", {useNewUrlParser:true});



var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'uploads')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
});
 
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });



const userSchema = {
    email : String,
    password: String,
    name: String
};

 

var imageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   img:
    {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String
    },
  name: String,
  dob: String,
  breed: String,
  details: String
  
 
});
 
 
module.exports = mongoose.model('Image', imageSchema);


const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);


app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.render("home");
});


app.get("/login", function(req,res){
    res.render("login");
});


app.get("/register", function(req,res){
    res.render("register");
});


app.get("/admin", function(req,res){
    res.render("adminlogin");
});

app.get("/addNew", function(req,res){
    res.render("addNewAnimal");
});

app.get("/showAdopted", function(req,res){
    res.render("showAdopted");
});

app.get("/viewAll", function(req,res){
    res.render("viewAll");
});

app.get('/proto', (req, res) => {
    imgModel.find({}, (err, items) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send('An error occurred', err);
        }
        else {
            res.render("prototype", { items: items });
        }
    });
});


app.post("/register", function(req,res){
     const newUser = new User({
        name : req.body.name,
        email: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password

     });

     newUser.save(function (err){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.redirect("proto");
        }
     });
});


app.post("/login", function(req, res){
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;
    

    User.findOne({email:username}, function(err,foundUser){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        } else{
            if (foundUser){
                if (foundUser.password === password){
                    res.render("secrets");
                }
            }
        }
    });
});


app.post("/adminlogin", function(req, res){
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;
    

    User.findOne({email:username}, function(err,foundUser){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        } else{
            if (foundUser){
                if (foundUser.password === password){
                    res.render("adminPage");
                }
            }
        }
    });
});

app.post("/proto",(req, res, next) =>{
  var obj = {
      name: req.body.username,
    
  }

    console.log(obj)


  });


app.post("/addNewAnimal",upload.single('image'), (req, res, next) =>{
  var obj = {
      name: req.body.petName,
      dob: req.body.petDob,
      breed: req.body.petBreed,
      details: req.body.petDescription,
      img: {
            data: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname + '/uploads/' + req.file.filename)),
            contentType: 'image/png'
        }
    
  }

    
  imgModel.create(obj, (err, item) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            // item.save();
            res.redirect('/proto');

    
  }

});
  console.log(obj.name)

  });




app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

and my /prototype.ejs

```
<%- include('partials/header') %>
<div class="row">

  <%  items.forEach(function(items){ %>
<div class="card col-lg-4 col-md-6">

  <img alt="John" style="width:100%" src="data:image/<%=items.img.contentType%>;base64,
                     <%=items.img.data.toString('base64')%>"> 
  <h6><%=items.name%></h6>
  <h6><%=items.dob%></h6>
    <h6><%=items.breed%></h6>
       <h6><%=items.details%></h6>

  <p><button>adopt</button></p>
   </div>
        <% }) %>



</div>



  <%- include('partials/footer') %>
```

and /register.ejs

```
<div class="container mt-5">
  <h1>Register</h1>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">

          <!-- Makes POST request to /register route -->
          <form action="/register" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Full Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
            </div>  
           <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Register</button>
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="card social-block">
        <div class="card-body">
          <a class="btn btn-block" href="/auth/google" role="button">
            <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
            Sign Up with Google
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> -->

  </div>
</div>

<%- include('partials/header') %>
```

and lastly adminPage.ejs

```
<%- include("partials/header"); -%>
    <section class="colored-section" id="adminTitle">

    <div class="container-fluid">

      <!-- Nav Bar -->

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">AAS</a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">

          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/addNew">Add new</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Show adopted</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#cta">View All</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </nav>


<%- include("partials/footer"); -%>
```

A detailed explanation would be really appreciated!!

Comment: You would need to keep some user info in the session.

Comment: How do i go about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved using Passport.js.

Which enables you to tap into fields such as req.user, which returns the current signed in authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing an application which requires user sign up, and subsequent authentication, I would suggest incorporating user authentication into your application using something like JSON Web Tokens (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken). Using Express, you should be able to create some authentication middleware (https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html). When you authenticate the user in the middleware function you write, you can place the user object that you get from Mongoose onto the request object that Express passes through to the route from middleware. Something like this,

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const User = require('../models/user')

const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ', '')
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'shhh')
        const user = await User.findOne({ _id: decoded._id, 'tokens.token': token })
        
        if (user) {
            req.user = user
            req.token = token
            next()
        } else {
            throw new Error()
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(401).send({ error: 'Please authenticate'})
    }
}

module.exports = auth
```

Of course, this is only half of the solution, because you will have to make sure to pass a valid token back to the client and store that token in your User model within your login route handler. Then you have to make sure that the client will pass a valid token to the server within the Authorization Header in the HTTP request. The key part that solves your problem is that line in the example above where you set `req.user = user` because you will have access to that exact user in your route handler on the req object, which allows you to determine which user has arrived at the route handler.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Honestly i'm just a rookie and do not fully grasp what you mean. mind further explaining please?

Comment: Have you used express middleware before?

Comment: How are you managing your login process? Are you locking down routes somehow so that only authenticated users can access them?

Comment: hey guys, i have been able to address thes issues by using passport, however i came up with another problem, if you could all kindly have a look at it.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67388391/why-does-nodejs-reference-error-say-not-defined?noredirect=1#comment119111958_67388391