# why does nodeJS reference error say not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

how to fix reference error  item not defined?
I'm trying to parse some data from my db  to adminPage.ejs. below is my code

I have data in db that ensures selectedPet is not null.
app.js

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email : String,
    password: String,
    selectedPet: String
});



userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

app.get("/adminPage", function(req,res){
    User.find({"selectedPet" : {$ne:null}}, function(err, foundUsers){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            if (foundUsers){
                res.render("adminPage", {userSelectedPet: foundUsers})
            }
        }
    });

});
```

and heres adminPage.ejs

```
<%userSelectedPet.forEach(function(user){ %>
  <li>
    <p> <%=user.selectedPet %> </p>
  </li>
<% }) %>
```

But i keep getting a reference error stating userSelectedPet not defined.

Below is the error

```
ReferenceError: /Users/curtis/Desktop/astonAnimalSantuary/views/adminPage.ejs:37
    35|   </section>
    36|   
 >> 37|   <%userSelectedPet.forEach(function(user){ %>
    38|     <li>
    39|       <p class="petDetails"> <%=user.selectedPet%> </p>
    40|     </li>

userSelectedPet is not defined
```

Comment: What is not defined? What is the error? Where does it come from?

Comment: i have added the error.

Comment: Have you been able to check the updated code ??